# imagio throws an error when i try to extract text

Tags: python-imageio

I am trying to package a computer vision software using pyinstaller. But python-imagio from easyocr seems to have a problem with something I suspect is handling formats. The Gui runs fine. I am able to capture images. But after capturing, when it gets to text extraction, it throws an error message and exits. I have followed the prompt to set the overwrite parameter to true in the format.py file, but this still won't cut it. Has anyone encountered the same problems with imageio? Please, I need feedback.

Here's the error message I get when I run from my command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 167, in run
  File "main.py", line 35, in ocr_text
  File "easyocr\easyocr.py", line 383, in readtext
    img, img_cv_grey = reformat_input(image)
  File "easyocr\utils.py", line 698, in reformat_input
    image = os.path.expanduser(image)
  File "easyocr\imgproc.py", line 12, in loadImage
    img = io.imread(img_file)           # RGB order
  File "skimage\io\_io.py", line 53, in imread
  File "skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 207, in call_plugin
  File "skimage\io\_plugins\imageio_plugin.py", line 10, in imread
  File "imageio\core\functions.py", line 159, in imread
    format : str
  File "imageio\core\imopen.py", line 194, in imopen
  File "imageio\config\plugins.py", line 101, in plugin_class
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Prospero\Desktop\occulus_App\dist\main\imageio\plugins\freeimage.py", line 513, in <module>
    _create_predefined_freeimage_formats()
  File "C:\Users\Prospero\Desktop\occulus_App\dist\main\imageio\plugins\freeimage.py", line 477, in _create_predefined_freeimage_formats
    formats.add_format(format)
  File "imageio\core\format.py", line 659, in add_format
    if overwrite:
ValueError: A Format named BMP-FI is already registered, use `overwrite=True` to replace.
```

Comment: Which version of ImageIO are you using? The latest version (ImageIO 2.15.0) does no longer have the `_create_predefined_freeimage_formats` function, which is causing you problems.